# Polymer1: addEventListener for Notify Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to call `window.addEventListener` on my custom behavior however im not having any luck getting it to work.

test-bahvior.html

```html
<script>
    "use strict";

    window.MyTest = window.MyTest || {};
    
    MyTest.Test = {
      properties: {
        globals: {
          type: Boolean,
          notify: true,
          value: false
        }
      },
    
      ready: function() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.globals = true;
            console.log('changed val ' + this.globals);
        }, 5000);
      },
    };
</script>
```

i am then trying to call`window.addEventListener("globals-changed", this._test);` in the `ready: function()` of another html file (myapp.html) however this._test doesnt seem to fire despite the setTimeout causing the value change.

I have been following the Polymer 1 docs:
https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#notify

Help is much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Polymer to detect the changes correctly (i.e. notify the `dom`), use the following:

```
this.set("globals", true);
```